# error TS1005: ':' expected TypeScript Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

I am getting below error when trying to build my Angular 6 app.

> ERROR in src/app/util/notification.service.ts(14,9): error TS1005:
>   ':' expected.

Here is the related code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

    timeOut: number = 5000;

    constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {}

    error(toast_msg, msg_title){

            this.toastr.error('<span class="now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53"></span> ' + toast_msg, msg_title, {
                this.timeOut
            });
   }

}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: @JoelHarkes `super()` is called for classes extending other classes. As for the OP `{this.timeOut}` won't work unles **both variables have the exact same name**. and `timeout` is different than `this.timeOut` : consider explicitly declaring it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
this.toastr.error('<span class="now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53"></span> ' + toast_msg, msg_title, {
  timeout: this.timeOut,
});
```

or, since rest of the parameters are passed as args:

```
this.toastr.error('<span class="now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53"></span> ' + toast_msg, msg_title, this.timeOut);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My Bad. It should be `timeout: this.timeOut`

Answer (score 3):

Error is related to *TypeScript* configuration.

Create your object by explicitly giving property name

```
{ timeout: this.timeOut }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, the property name is missing in my code. That's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Issue with you are not using key value pair for timeOut

Try this,

```
error(toast_msg, msg_title) {
        this.toastr.error('<span class="now-ui-icons ui-1_bell-53"></span> ' + toast_msg, msg_title, {
            timeOut: this.timeOut
        });
    }
```